# Aligning list view values

Tags: android

I have a layout which has a listview that looks like a table.
The list items has multiple views. How would align the list items' values with the headers? Of course, I would make my own custom list item view but is that possible through xml?

```
        Header 1 --------------- Header 2 -------------- Header 3

Item 1  Value 1                  Value 2                 Value 3

Item 2  Value 1                  Value 2                 Value 3

Item 3  Value 1                  Value 2                 Value 3
```

Comment: yes it is possible with xml

Comment: Yes everything is possible. We just need some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your layout this way

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Header1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Header1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Header1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

lits_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Item1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Value1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Value2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Value3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```